# TypeScript generated javascript files are not uploading to web server from Visual Studio online CD builds

Tags: azure, typescript, tfsbuild, azure-devops

Using latest of everything.  VS2013 Ultimate with all the patches.  TypeScript 1.0 built in.  Visual Studio online continous integration script to publish to Azure Webrole.

Problem: the generated js file is not getting deployed to web server after build completes.  I cannot include it into the solution, because then build server complains about a generation violation (forgot the error, and basically including generated .js files is not recommended)

I've googled a little and found that I may possibly need to remove following line from my csproj file:

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

This however, did not help.

Any suggestions?  Anything I can provide from the logs to help assist this?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

OK, this was definately a user error.  We only had the Debug configuration for Typescript to generate .js files.  In the Release/other configurations, Typescript was not configured to generate .js properly.

Comment: You're not along @Igorek :) https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201409/Blog/Cannot-Compile-External-Modules-Unless-The-Module-Flag-Is-Provided/